# Get data from Push Notification message

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

When receive a push notification and my application is totally closed, how can handle this info?

for example: when the user open the application from notification message, how i get data from the push notification? (Data: "UserName: Hello, i'm human" ). When app start, i want get String "Hello, I'm human".

Is there a method for this action?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You need to poll the server for the data when your app is launched from the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,If your app is opened by clicking the toast notification, you can implement the following method in the page where your app is opened. You can access the parameters passed in the query string of the wp:Param parameter of the toast notification.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    //  If we navigated to this page
    // from the MainPage, the DefaultTitle parameter will be "FromMain".  If we navigated here
    // when the secondary Tile was tapped, the parameter will be "FromTile".
    textBlockFrom.Text = "Navigated here from " + this.NavigationContext.QueryString["NavigatedFrom"];
   }
```

[sample here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx)